# C++ Set default argument for a function parameter?

Tags: c++

C++ Set default argument for a function parameter? I'm trying to set a **Void Function** as a default arg for a param but I get a
**`C++ no suitable constructor exists to convert from to`**
Error.

Current Code,

```
void VoidFunction(int a, int b, int c){} 
inline void Center(function<void()> Func = VoidFunction(0,1,2));
```

Comment: pleae include a [mcve] of your code and the complete error message in the question

Comment: VoidFunction is just a void VoidFunction(int a, int b, int c){}

Comment: You are calling the function. To get a function pointer write `&VoidFunction`

Comment: largest_prime_is_463035818, Thank you, that fixed it!

Comment: Except that doesn't pass (1, 2, 3) so it doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might mean "how to make the default an anonymous callable that executes `VoidFunction(0,1,2)`", in which case there's [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/597a80673c0358ae)**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void VoidFunction(int i, int = 0, int = 0) { 
    switch(i) {
        case 0: std::cout << "Hello\n"; break;
        case 1: std::cout << "World\n"; break;
        case 99: std::cout << "Bye\n"; break;
    }
}

inline void Front(std::function<void()> Func = std::bind(VoidFunction, 0, 1, 2)) {
    Func();
}
inline void Center(std::function<void()> Func = [] { VoidFunction(1, 2, 3); }) {
    Func();
}

int main() {
    Front();
    Center();

    Front([] { VoidFunction(99); });
}
```

Prints

```
Hello
World
Bye
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void function(int a; char b, int c=1) {
....
}
```

You can use any type of return value. The only thing that is important is default parameters have to be the last parameter in the row. You can use multiple default parameter as well.